# I don't understand why I am receiving the following errors

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I am pretty sure that I have all this right. I am thinking that somehow my syntax is wrong, but I am having no luck trying to Google as to why it is wrong. Here is my code:

```
namespace Exercise1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Values aValue = new Values();

            //set array
            int[] number = new int[12];

            //ask user for input
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 0 and 10: ");
            aValue.InValue = Console.ReadLine(); //Read input
            aValue.IntValue = int.Parse(aValue.InValue); //convert string to int

            while (aValue.IntValue != -99) //user has not stopped program

                if (aValue.IntValue > 10 || aValue.IntValue < 0) //valid value
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you! Please enter '-99' when you are ready to finsih.");
            aValue.InValue = Console.ReadLine(); //read input
            aValue.IntValue = int.Parse(aValue.InValue); //convert string to int
            number[aValue.IntValue]++; //add input to corresponding array box

????        else 
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid value.");
            aValue.InvalidValueCount()++;

            namespace Exercise1
            {
                class Values
                {
                    private string inValue;
                    public string InValue { get; set; }

                    private int intValue;
                    public int IntValue { get; set; }

                    private int validValueCount;
                    public int ValidValueCount { get; set; }

                    private int invalidValueCount;
                    public int InvalidValueCount() { 
                        invalidValueCount = 0;
                        return invalidValueCount;
                    }
                }
           }
```

Error messages are as follows:

> Invalid expression term 'else'
>   ; expected    (after "else")
>   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement    (after "`number[aValue.IntValue]++;`")
>   The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer  (after "`aValue.InvalidValueCount()++;`")

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are your curly braces?

Comment: It gave me an error whenever I put those in with the While Loop.

Comment: You DO need curly braces for the `while` and `if` blocks, otherwise how would the compiler know when to start/end the block? This is not Python, blocks are not determined by indentation in C#. You should probably look up some examples on how to write while/if statements in C#.

Comment: while (aValue.IntValue != -99) //user has not stopped program
            {

            if (aValue.IntValue > 10 || aValue.IntValue < 0) //valid value
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you! Please enter '-99' when you are ready to finsih.");
                aValue.InValue = Console.ReadLine(); //read input
                aValue.IntValue = int.Parse(aValue.InValue); //convert string to int
                number[aValue.IntValue]++; //add input to corresponding array box
            }
            else 
            {    
    ...

That still gives me the same errors

Comment: I have indented the code as the compiler "sees" it to help you understand your errors. You have an else that suddenly appears unconnected with the previous if, as you aren't using braces properly.

Comment: Useless title does not contribute to the value of the site to others.

Comment: Nice example of what can go wrong when code blocks aren't properly delimited. ALWAYS open up a scope (curly braces) after an if/else/foreach/whatever, even if it's for one line of code. Not sure what the question's title should be though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need curly braces around multiline blocks of code after while/if/else

```
        while (aValue.IntValue != -99) //user has not stopped program
        { 
            if (aValue.IntValue > 10 || aValue.IntValue < 0) //valid value
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you! Please enter '-99' when you are ready to finsih.");
                aValue.InValue = Console.ReadLine(); //read input
                aValue.IntValue = int.Parse(aValue.InValue); //convert string to int
                number[aValue.IntValue]++; //add input to corresponding array box
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid value.");
                aValue.InvalidValueCount()++; // <-- this is your error
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did that, and now my errors are the following:

"Invalid expression term 'else'"
"; expected" (after else)
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" (after curly brace before else)
and, "The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property, or indexer" (after "aValue.InvalidValueCount()++;")

Comment: You can't use the increment operator `++` on the result of a function call

Comment: I made aValue.InvalidValueCount() to no longer be a function, and it worked. Thanks for your help!